# Android - Failed to access Database from another app using Content Provider

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I've searching for many other answers about this failure, and no one of them solved my problem.

I have two apps, the app1 is implemented with Content Provider, and one database called students. This db is accessed normally inside app1.
But, when I fetch database from the app2, I've facing this error:

> Failed to find provider info for
>   com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider

The code that are fetching students db is the same from both apps:

```
Uri myURI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider/students");
ContentProviderClient myCR = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(myURI);
try {
    Cursor c = myCR.query(myURI, null, null, null, "name");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            Toast.makeText(this,
                  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constantes._ID)) +
                  ", " +  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( Constantes.NAME)) +
                  ", " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( Constantes.GRADE)),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Debuging app 2, `myCR` comes with `null`. Them crashes application.

With my searches of this problem, I found many information that I need to grant access from package of Content Provider. Below are my manifests:

***Manifest form app1:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.a436236692.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:permission="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:readPermission="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.READ_DATABASE"
            android:writePermission="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

***Manifest form app2:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.a436236692.testes">

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_DATABASE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:readPermission="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.READ_DATABASE"
    android:writePermission="com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.a436236692.testes.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.a436236692.testes.ContentProviderExampleActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Even with permissions, inside the app1, Read and Write and other things, that I include inside the manifests, they do not affect the result.

Thanks

Comment: you need `com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider.READ_DATABASE` in `<uses-perrmision .../>` in app 2, and `WRITE_DATABASE` too

Comment: That permission is failing building of the project, with error _Error:Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ''._

Comment: what invalid character? maybe you cannot have numbers in `android:name` ?

Comment: I really don't know what happened, cause when I build the project, the error doesn't occured again. So, nevermind this point. But that not solved the question error. I updated manifests on question. tks =)

Comment: what is `android:multiprocess` used for? tried for testing to remove it?

Comment: Sure, I've removed the multiprocess flag. Doesn't work anyway. I've tested any permissions from provider, and in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) inform that "Multiprocess may improve performance by reducing the overhead of interprocess communication, but it also increases the memory footprint of each process."

Comment: Anyway, I don't believe that is error about permission on manifest. There is another explanation for that issue?